# Graphic design draw invisible path of svg using pencil inkscape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, inkscape, text-on-path

[image]

I trying to make a educational video and for that purpose am using videoscribe .

and i dont have illustrator .

I want to trace the text in the image so it would appear as handwriting animation in the videoscribe .How to do this in inkscape.
The illustrator example is shown here

https://youtu.be/JfEr6rKJp74?t=1

**EDIT:-**
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design SE. Can you please [edit] your question to elaborate what exactly want to trace, the outline or the strokes of the text? Also note that you can entirely skip the step in the linked video as Inkscape has a built-in LaTeX renderer. Finally note that Inkscape is not really aimed at animations. And as a complete aside: *Res* should be upright and *z=a* be below it.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft thanks for the warm welcome :) .Sure I would add the details .I tried to find the latex to text converter in inkscape but failed to find it and Tried extension by downloading .48.5 verion of it and then installing one but it did not work .Right now can you please watch the https://youtu.be/JfEr6rKJp74?t=1 video .What I want is to do a stroke over the text but without being visible like in the video .Sorry If I cannot express myself clearly to you .I was thinking of how to be more clear sorry tell me if you need any more information

Comment: *Tried extension by downloading .48.5 verion of it and then installing one but it did not work* – That’s a pretty old version. Also, I strongly suggest that you fix this problem first. — Taking a closer look at the video, it does not only do something you do not need to do (due to said LaTeX renderer), it also does what it does in a pretty convoluted and inaccurate way. Best you forget that you saw it. — *tell me if you need any more information* – Can you sketch an example of the desired outcome? — Finally, please [edit] new information into your question.

Comment: I will add a gif to showing exactly what I am facing right now and what I need .Before that can you tell me one thing I started with inscakpe .91 I saw no lex support for it and is there any plugin for .91

Comment: You should find it under *Extensions → Render → LaTeX formula.* We even have [a question for this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/88027/19174).

Comment: that is the problem there is not Latex formula option under and this what set me off in this wild goose chase

Comment: added the gif trying to show what I am trying to do the image should be written like the text below it for that to happen the stroke has to be invisible and background should be visible or else I would need latex formula to appear out of thin air in inkscape apparently this functionality is missing and there is lot of google searches regarding that and I could not find a working solution for it.Stuck with this for a couple of days .

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Windows, the LaTeX extension in Inkscape has to be installed separately along with another bunch of software including: ImageMagick, pstoedit, Ghostscript, GS view, TeXtex. There's a guide [here](https://people.orie.cornell.edu/jmd388/design/guides/textext.pdf) if you want to try to install those. However, despite following this guide, I haven't been able to get it to work with the newest version of Inkscape 0.92 running on Windows.

You can save yourself some trouble by using [LaTeX Preview](http://www.tlhiv.org/ltxpreview/) and set it to SVG, and then download the generated SVG to use in Inkscape.

If you want to turn the SVG glyphs generated by LaTeX Preview to paths so you can see them/edit them, then use the Edit Paths by Nodes Tool to select each glyph one at a time and click Edit > Clone > Unlink Clone.

As for invisible strokes, just remove the stroke and fill in Inkscape. The path will still be there.

Example of LaTeX Preview generated SVG glyphs, turned to paths, and no fill/stroke, over a visible background.

[image]

Comment: The edit clone and unlink  clone stuff did not work for me

Comment: Did you select each glyph one at a time before unlinking the clone?  Also make sure in your Preferences > Tools > Node, under Path Outline, that you select "Always show outline".  Also once you have applied no stroke and fill to the glyph shapes, and then deselect the glyph, you won't be able to see or select the path again when you select it, but the path will still be there.  However you can select the path in the XML editor.